# Can't back to default UEFI BIOS - Thinkpad T480

Tags: bios, uefi, thinkpad

May you help me with the following:
I switched to Legacy mode to install a stand-alone Linux on my Thinkpad T480. I didn't succeed to Back to default UEFI BIOS (the relevant entries in BIOS are greyed out).
May you help me to reactivate 'Load Setup Defaults' in Thinkpad Setup?

Comment: Installing any OS in Legacy mode in 2022 is ridiculous. Any major Liniux distro supports and recommends UEFI mode for UEFI hardware since a decade ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I agree, but what can I do now?

Comment: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t480_ug_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks but I can't reverse changes made in BIOS!

Comment: Sure you can. Of course there will be many options greyed out after selecting Legacy only because those options are exclusively for UEFI. But once you select "Both" or "UEFI only" they will no longer be greyed out.

Comment: I tried to reset BIOS default by this method: https://fr.ifixit.com/Tutoriel/Lenovo+ThinkPad+T480+CMOS+Battery+Replacement/139963 but without success (BIOS locked, even after BIOS upgrade under win10).

Comment: With UEFI such tricks don't work. Settings are stored in a non-volatile area so simply shutting down power or removing CMOS battery won't change a thing. Again, there's NO mention of any "reset to factory defaults" in the manual and it isn't needed anyway.